# chart width shifting when scrolling

Tags: c#, charts

when I scroll by axisX my chart is shifting. I think it happens because I use custom lablels. How to fix axisX width?

```
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = false;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(1, 250);

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = false;

            //custom labels
            //...
            //...
                 if (i % 13 == 0)
                 {
                     CustomLabel CL = new CustomLabel();
                     CL.FromPosition = i - 13;
                     CL.ToPosition = i + 13;
                     CL.Text = L[i].Item1.ToString("d MMM\r\nHH:mm");//+"\n"+L[i].Item1.ToString("HH:mm");

                     chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(CL);
                 }
              //...
              //..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most, if not all, chart elements have some sort of size property. In your case, you can use the `InnerPlotPosition` property of the `ChartArea`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.innerplotposition(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details, but it might look something like:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 75; // this will make the plotting area width 75% of the whole chart area width
chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 60; // this makes the plotting area height 60% of the chart area height
```

or you could do something like:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(5, 10, 75, 60);
```

which would set the location and size of the plotting area all at once.

One thing to note with this property is that the sizes are not actual pixel sizes, but percentages of the size of the `ChartArea`. It takes a lot of fiddling and trial-and-error to get them right, and you may need to handle the `Form`'s `Resize` event in some cases to keep the chart looking good when the window gets resized.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the problem is caused by the right-most label appearing and disappearing during scrolling. If so you can disable it by setting `ChartAreas[n].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible` to false. That way you don't need to fight with InnerPlotPosition values.